# Issue during manually enter sub-menu using query in joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla3.0

As per client requirement in Joomla 3.4, I have to add menu manually from admin custom component.

I added menu successfully in table but due to *LFT and RGT* filed for position menu in front side create a problem to display properly.

I added sub-menu under parent menu and display sub-menu on other parent due to position problem. I checked it in database but change position of all menus on every entry automatically.

Not understand how its count.

Can any one have a idea or suggestion how to enter menu using query?